# Arangodb - @include configuration file

Tags: arangodb

In configuration file I can put

```
@include some_other_file
```

The "issue" is that this "some_other_file.conf" has to be under:

```
/etc/arangodb3/some_other_file.conf
```

I tried absolute path, but it seams I can include other files only if they are in /etc/arangodb3/.
/etc/arangodb3/ corresponds to @SYSCONFDIR@ variable I can use in configuration file.

Is there any way to include configuration file from any location ?
Or maybe some way to set @SYSCONFDIR@ to point to directory I want ?

Comment: can you retry with current arangodb 3.1.RC2 whether this is still a problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been meanwhile resolved in ArangoDB 3.1.